# Make a single option readyonly in Yii 1.x dropdown list

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii1.x

I was trying to create a dropdown list in Yii 1.x as follows.

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('userroles', $role_id, $roles, array('class'=>'span12'));?>
```

Here `$roles` contains the list of all roles in `role_id => role_name` format. What i am looking for is to make readonly a single item from the dropdown.

Can someone help me to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `"disabled"=>"disabled"` in your dropdown, this will disable the drop down from being selected, like:

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('userroles', $role_id, $roles, array('class'=>'span12', "disabled"=>"disabled"));?>
```

If you want to disable any one of the option from being selected then, you can do this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('userroles', $role_id, $roles, array('class'=>'span12', 'options'=>array("myValue"=>array('disabled'=>'disabled'))));?>
```

Here, users won't be able to select `myValue` from the dropdown.

Comment: this will disable all the options in the dropdown. I want to selectively disable a single option. Not all.

Comment: @TismonVarghese can you explain a bit more ? Do you want to disable that option from being selected, why not remove it then ?